# Cannot write to a textfile using timer in C#

Tags: c#, timer, filestream, streamwriter

I am still newbie to C# and I'm making a test program that writes the DateTime.Now every second. I tried using this and it worked:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:\Hello.txt", true);
sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
sw.Close();
```

However, when I tried including a FileStream, it didn't work. What seems to be the problem? Here's my code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Hello.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
sw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Note: I am using a timer, it executes the code every second..

Update:
I tried placing the code(the one that has the filestream) inside a button (w/out timer). Whenever I clicked the button, it just replaces the line in the textfile.. This is a code that appends a text to the textfile:
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:\Hello.txt", true);

How will I do it in a filestream? I cannot use FileMode.Append in FileStream because it required=s the FileAccess to be write-only.

Comment: "it didn't work" is far too vague for us to help you. Please give more details. Oh, and you should use `using` statements to close resources in a more robust way.

Comment: please provide Exception details and make sure that file is not open or in use by another process. I dont think this has anything to do with the timer.

Comment: Don't you think using Filemode.Append is better...just a suggestion.

Comment: @pssk - I think it should show an error if it is being used by another process, but I'll check it again..

Comment: @Ravi - I tried setting breakpoints, it passes through the code that writes the text but still doesn't write in the textfile..

Comment: @Abhineet - I'll check on that.. Thanks

Comment: Thank you to all that replied. I'll try all your suggestions.. Will be posting updates. Thanks!

Comment: Googling your question gave me a lot of links but it seems your code is correct. But better use "Flush" - it will write everything in the internal buffer to disk. If you use it after each byte you write, all will be on the disk but this has a very bad performance. Best thing may be to use Flush manually after each important block of data you wrote and before Close.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are executing the code every second then its not a good idea to create `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` object everytime, because sometimes the file will remain under lock condition and the filestream will miss to acquire the handle.

As you are writing to single file its good to initialize a `FileStream` and subsequent `StreamWriter` in the constructor while leaving the refrence to them in class scope;then calling it every second on a thread for `sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);` should help.

And further never miss `try catch` in a filestream. They help a lot to locate the discrepancies.

Comment: Are you sure, it really closes within a second????Take the snap of exception logged, you'll learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `StreamWriter.Flush()` before `StreamWriter.Close()`.

Answer (score 0):

May be try to use File?

```
File.AppendAllText(@"D:\Hello.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

or

```
File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Hello.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

to overwrite

Comment: I have to use FileStream because it has the filemode, fileacces and fileshare which I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this because it works fine for me. If it does not work for you, you have to add more details

```
        using (var fs = new FileStream("path", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs) { AutoFlush = true })
            {
                sw.WriteLine("my text");
            }
        }
```

But remember I would not create it every second. Why don t you store a Streamwriter object as field when you call Timer.Start?
So you would not have to create it every second. (rememer to dispose it when you stop the timer)

Answer (score 0):

Should work:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Hello.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it.. :) I just have to use FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write as an argument in the filestream. Reason for not doing FileMode.Append earlier is because it needs FileAccess to be Write only. I thought switching the FileAcess to Write only will prevent the user from reading the file. So stupid of me.. This is my code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Hello.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        lbTimer.Items.Add(DateTime.Now);
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();

    }
```

Last question, what is setting the FileAccess to Write only for when you can still read it?

Answer (score -1):

You might wanna look here

**How to: Write to a Text File (C# Programming Guide)**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: Don't you think this is not an answer, just a comment?